# H2 database, insert by selecting results from CSVREAD

Tags: sql, csv, h2

I have a CSV file like

```
1,hello,13
2,world,14
3,ciao,26
```

I'm trying to use `CSVREAD` function to read this file into database, like this

```
insert into my_table( id, message, code ) values (
  select convert( "id",bigint ), "message", convert( "code", bigint)
  from CSVREAD( 'myfile.csv', 'id,message,code', null )
);
```

For some reason I keep on getting `SQL error stating that the column count does not match.`

The table is created with Hibernate/GORM and contains the fields I try to insert into.

The select itself seems to work, or at least it does not cause any errors when executed alone. **What's wrong with my statement?**

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You have used

```
insert into my_table(...) values (select ...)
```

but you should use, as documented in the [SQL railroad diagrams](http://h2database.com/html/grammar.html#insert),

```
insert into my_table(...) select ...
```

Actually, for H2, [it is a bit faster if you create the table as follows](http://h2database.com/html/performance.html#fast_import), but I understand it is not always possible:

```
create table my_table(...) as select ...
```

Comment: Thanks @Thomas. At this point of development GORM/Hibernate creates the tables for me, where I only init the data from CSV files. When the app matures, the option of using create table to also include the data as well.