# Comparing two text large files with URLs in Java with external memory only?

Tags: java, sorting, diff

I have the following scenario:

- url text file A
- url text file B

Each file's size is around 4Gb.

I need to calculate:

- all urls in A that are not in B
- all urls in B that are not in A

All of the Java-diff examples I'm finding online load the entire list in memory (either with a Map or using an MMap solution). My system doesn't have swap and lacks the memory to be able to do this without External-Memory.

Does anyone know of a solution for this?

This project can do huge file sorts without eating up tons of memory https://github.com/lemire/externalsortinginjava

I am looking for something similar, but for generating diffs. I'm going to start by trying to implement this using that project as a baseline.

Comment: `BufferedReader` ? Are they many 'url' in both file or many text and a few url ? => is loading all URL in memory a solution ?

Comment: hi. no unfortunately. i tried that already and my cloud vms are too small to handle in-memory solutions or any memory mapping. it needs to be external memory only

Comment: From the way you are describing it you would have to do a huge amount of passes.

Comment: The external sorting in java project I mentioned above is able to sort these files in a manner of a few seconds. so i'm thinking it's not going to be too horrible once I come up with the algorithm.

Comment: Are all URLs in each text file unique?  If not, what is the size of unique URLs in each file?

Comment: there are a lot of common urls between the two. typically going to be a small number of diff files (1000's diffs, 1,000,000's of similarities)

Comment: I'm talking about within one file.  I'm wondering if you can reduce the file by enough if you remove duplicates from a single file.

Comment: oh i see. no unfortunately. no dupes at all. already removed.

Answer (score 1):

If system has enough storage, you can do this via DB. For example :

Create an H2 or sqlite DB (data stored on disk, allocate as much
    cache as system can afford) 
Load text file in tables A and B (create index on 'url' column)

```
select url from A where URL not in (select distinct url from B)
select url from B where URL not in (select distinct url from A)
```

Comment: i can try that.

Comment: query is just an example, do look at execution plan to see if query can be optimized

Comment: wasn't even able to load the data into the table in the first place without completely killing the machine.

Comment: Which DB is it (H2 or sqlite? )

Comment: was using h2's csvload. very bad. can try sqlite

Comment: Try this : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19299589/h2-database-insert-by-selecting-results-from-csvread

Comment: Specifically : http://h2database.com/html/performance.html#fast_import   (jdbc:h2:~/test;LOG=0;CACHE_SIZE=65536;LOCK_MODE=0;UNDO_LOG=0 and create table my_table(...) as select ...)

Comment: performance was very poor. i just coded something that suits my scenario, posted it below

Answer (score 0):

Here is a gist of the solution I came up with: https://gist.github.com/nddipiazza/16cb2a0d23ee60a07121893c26065de4

```
import com.google.common.collect.Sets;
import org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils;
import org.apache.commons.io.LineIterator;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Set;

public class DiffTextFilesUtil {
  static public int CHUNK_SIZE = 100000;

  static public class DiffResult {
    public Set<String> addedVals = new HashSet<>();
    public Set<String> removedVals = new HashSet<>();
  }

  /**
   * Gets diff result of two sorted files with each other.
   * @param lhs left hand file - sort this using com.google.code.externalsortinginjava:externalsortinginjava:0.2.5
   * @param rhs right hand file - sort this using com.google.code.externalsortinginjava:externalsortinginjava:0.2.5
   * @return DiffResult.addedVals were added from lhs to rhs. DiffResult.removedVals were removed from lhs to rhs.
   * @throws IOException
   */
  public static DiffResult diff(File lhs, File rhs) throws IOException {

    DiffResult diffResult = new DiffResult();

    LineIterator lhsIter = FileUtils.lineIterator(lhs);
    LineIterator rhsIter = FileUtils.lineIterator(rhs);

    String lhsTop = null;
    String rhsTop = null;
    while (lhsIter.hasNext()) {
      int ct = CHUNK_SIZE;

      Set<String> setLhs = Sets.newHashSet();
      Set<String> setRhs = Sets.newHashSet();
      while (lhsIter.hasNext() && --ct > 0) {
        lhsTop = lhsIter.nextLine();
        setLhs.add(lhsTop);
      }
      while (rhsIter.hasNext()) {
        if (rhsTop != null && rhsTop.compareTo(lhsTop) > 0) {
          break;
        } else if (rhsTop != null && rhsTop.compareTo(lhsTop) == 0) {
          setRhs.add(rhsTop);
          rhsTop = null;
          break;
        } else if (rhsTop != null) {
          setRhs.add(rhsTop);
        }
        rhsTop = rhsIter.next();
      }
      if (rhsTop != null) {
        setRhs.add(rhsTop);
      }
      Sets.difference(setLhs, setRhs).copyInto(diffResult.removedVals);
      Sets.difference(setRhs, setLhs).copyInto(diffResult.addedVals);
    }
    return diffResult;
  }
}
```