# Java Program to print the duplicate line from a single file which is of 100GB

Tags: java, heap-memory

So the scenario is we have 2GB RAM and a 100 GB text file. Our task is to print the duplicate line and its count. We have only a single-core processor.
One solution could be we can generate a hashcode of each line and store it into Hashmap with the count. But the problem is we have only 2GB RAM.
Let me know the approach to this solution.

Comment: How many lines does the 100GB text file have, can you estimate it?

Comment: Well, unless these "lines" are _really_ huge,  it's gotta be in the hundreds of millions to tens of billions...

Comment: Is this a job interview question? because otherwise copy the file into a disk and use a more modern computer to deal with this task.

Comment: Why use the "parallel-processing" tag if you only have one CPU core?

Comment: Buying a more powerful computer is much cheaper than inventing and implementing an algorithm to cope with the limited resources.

Comment: Please give proper java solution, extending RAM, modern computer all are good but we have limited 2GB RAM.

Comment: Perhaps this [Stack Overflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63521500/how-to-find-difference-line-based-in-sorted-large-text-files-in-java-without-l/63581608#63581608) would be helpful.

Answer (score 1):

The following algorithm is not very performant. It should only ilustrate the idea of what I would do.

```
Create an empty second file e.g. `./cache.data`.
Load the first line (l1) from the origin file. Initialize a counter with 0.
Read all lines (ln) from the origin file one by one (loop) 
  compare ln with the l1.
  If they differ 
    write the line ln into the created cache file 
    continue the loop
  if they do not differ
    counter++
    continue the loop
if counter > 0
  write out the l1 line and the counter (only the dups) 
        or counter + 1 (dups + l1) 
Replace the origin file with the cache file and create a new empty cache file
start from the beginning as long as there are lines in the source file
```

You can improve this algorithm be comparing more than one line at once. Then you need also more counters, one for each line to compare. And you have to be sure that there are no duplicate lines among the compare lines.

Comment: we have 100GB file. comparing each line with itself is not feasible. and also how can we put 100GB file in 2GB RAM. What is the process to load 100GB file in 2GB RAM.

Comment: You don't need to compare each line with itself. Without comparing each lines with each other you can not find the duplicates. Your idea was to build hashes of the lines. That would be more work than comparing two lines. You do not have to hold the 100 GB in the RAM; only two lines at a time. Of cause, if the finle consists of only a few lines then each line would be to large for the memory. ;-)  But then you could search for the line breaks and compare each of the few lines character by character with a random file access.